# How to set ontouch listener for something drawn using canvas: Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, ontouchlistener

I have a custom view in which i am drawing one big circle and a small circle on the edge of this big circle.

I would like to move the small circle and so would like to have a ontouch listener only for the small circle.

Could some please tell me how to set the ontouch listener for only the small circle.

```
public class ThermoView extends View{

    private ImageView mThermostatBgrd;
    private ImageView mCurTempArrow;
    private ImageView mSetPointIndicator;
    public static final int THEMROSTAT_BACKGROUND = 0;
    public static final int THEMROSTAT_CURR_TEMP = 1;
    public static final int THEMROSTAT_SET_POINT = 2;

    private float mViewCentreX;
    private float mViewCentreY;
    private float mThermostatRadius;

    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mPaintCurTemp;
    private Paint mPaintSetTemp;
    private Paint mPaintOverrideTemp;
    private Paint mPaintCurTempIndicator;

    private Boolean mManualOverride = false;
    private double mManualOverrideAngle;

    private int mMaxTemp = 420;
    private int mMinTemp = 120;

    private RectF mCurrTempBox;
    private float mCurTempCircleX;
    private float mCurTempCircleY;
    private Matrix mMatrix;



    public double getManualOverrideAngle() {
        return mManualOverrideAngle;
    }

    public void setManualOverrideAngle(double mManualOverrideAngle) {
        this.mManualOverrideAngle = mManualOverrideAngle;
    }

    public RectF getCurrTempBox() {
        if (mCurrTempBox == null){
            mCurrTempBox = new RectF();
        }
        return mCurrTempBox;
    }

    public void setCurrTempBox(RectF mCurrTempBox) {
        this.mCurrTempBox = mCurrTempBox;
    }


    public Boolean getManualOverride() {
        return mManualOverride;
    }

    public void setManualOverride(Boolean mManualOverride) {
        this.mManualOverride = mManualOverride;
    }

    public ThermoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Path smallCirle = new Path();
        int viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        mViewCentreX = viewWidth/2;
        mViewCentreY = viewHeight/2;
        float paddingPercent = 0.2f;
        int thermostatThickness = 20;
        mThermostatRadius = (int) ((Math.min(mViewCentreX, mViewCentreY)*(1- paddingPercent))); 

        if (mPaint == null){
            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(thermostatThickness);

        mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000); 

        Path arcPath = new Path();

        RectF container = new RectF();
        container.set(mViewCentreX - mThermostatRadius, mViewCentreY - mThermostatRadius, 
                                    mViewCentreX + mThermostatRadius, mViewCentreY + mThermostatRadius);
        arcPath.addArc(container, 120, 300);
        canvas.drawPath(arcPath, mPaint);



        int dummyCurTemp = 200;
        if (mPaintCurTemp == null){
            mPaintCurTemp = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }
        mPaintCurTemp.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mPaintCurTemp.setTextSize(100);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(dummyCurTemp), mViewCentreX, mViewCentreY, mPaintCurTemp);


        if (this.mManualOverride == false){

            double angle = (360-120-(300/(mMaxTemp - mMinTemp))*(dummyCurTemp-mMinTemp))*(Math.PI/180);

            this.mCurTempCircleX = (float) (mViewCentreX + mThermostatRadius*(Math.cos(angle)));
            this.mCurTempCircleY = (float) (mViewCentreY - mThermostatRadius*(Math.sin(angle)));

            if (mCurrTempBox == null){
                mCurrTempBox = new RectF();
            }
            if (mPaintCurTempIndicator == null){
                mPaintCurTempIndicator = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            }


            mPaintCurTempIndicator.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaintCurTempIndicator.setStrokeWidth(thermostatThickness/2);
            mPaintCurTempIndicator.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mCurrTempBox.set(mCurTempCircleX-50, mCurTempCircleY-50, mCurTempCircleX+50, mCurTempCircleY+50);
            smallCirle.addCircle(mCurTempCircleX, mCurTempCircleY, 50, Direction.CW);
            canvas.drawPath(smallCirle, mPaintCurTempIndicator);





        }else{



            if (mCurrTempBox == null){
                mCurrTempBox = new RectF();
            }
            if (mPaintCurTempIndicator == null){
                mPaintCurTempIndicator = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            }
            if (mMatrix == null){
                mMatrix = new Matrix();
            }
            //mMatrix.reset();


            mMatrix.postRotate((float) (mManualOverrideAngle), mViewCentreX,mViewCentreY);

            //mMatrix.postTranslate(mViewCentreX, mViewCentreY);
            mPaintCurTempIndicator.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaintCurTempIndicator.setStrokeWidth(thermostatThickness/2);
            mPaintCurTempIndicator.setColor(Color.GREEN);



            canvas.concat(mMatrix);

            smallCirle.addCircle(mCurTempCircleX, mCurTempCircleY, 50, Direction.CW);
            canvas.drawPath(smallCirle, mPaintCurTempIndicator);


        }





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    mInitialX = event.getX();
                    mInitialY = event.getY();

                    RectF touchedAt = new RectF(mInitialX-10, mInitialY-10, mInitialX+10, mInitialY+10);
                    RectF indicatorAt = mThermoStatView.getCurrTempBox();
                    if (RectF.intersects(indicatorAt, touchedAt)){
                        this.isIndicatorSelected = true;
                        mThermoStatView.setManualOverride(true);

                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (this.isIndicatorSelected == true){

                        float angle = (float) (180*Math.atan2(event.getY() - mThermostatHeight/2, event.getX() - mThermostatWidth/2) / Math.PI);
                        mThermoStatView.setManualOverrideAngle(angle);
                        mThermoStatView.invalidate();
                        //mThermoStatView.requestLayout();


                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (this.isIndicatorSelected == true){
                        this.isIndicatorSelected = false;

                    }
                    break;
            }


            return true;


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this.  Create your own Circle class which extends view with properties for size, colour, position etc and override ondraw to draw as you want.  Add it to your layout and set onClick as usual.  Well, you can do it, but it's much harder.  Get the raw touch events and use collision detection to figure out if a circle has been touched.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you need to override the view object's onTouchEvent method, looking at the MotionEvent object and figuring out if the touched point was within your small circle or not.

Comment: try this link it works fine for me 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437997/drawing-2-circles-on-a-canvas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this (this is a little modified version of MyView i already posted as an answer for your previous question):

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private final static String TAG = "Main.MyView";

    private static final float CX = 0;
    private static final float CY = 0;
    private static final float RADIUS = 20;
    private static final float BIGRADIUS = 50;
    private static final int NORMAL_COLOR = 0xffffffff;
    private static final int PRESSED_COLOR = 0xffff0000;

    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mSmallCircle;
    private Path mCircle;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private float mAngle;

    private int mSmallCircleColor;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint();

        mSmallCircle = new Path();
        mSmallCircle.addCircle(BIGRADIUS + RADIUS + CX, CY, RADIUS, Direction.CW);
        mSmallCircleColor = NORMAL_COLOR;

        mCircle = new Path();
        mCircle.addCircle(0, 0, BIGRADIUS, Direction.CW);

        mMatrix = new Matrix();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mSmallCircleColor = NORMAL_COLOR;
            invalidate();
            return false;
        }
        float w2 = getWidth() / 2f;
        float h2 = getHeight() / 2f;
        float r = 0;
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            float[] pts = {
                    BIGRADIUS + RADIUS + CX, CY
            };
            mMatrix.mapPoints(pts);
            r = (float) Math.hypot(event.getX() - pts[0], event.getY() - pts[1]);
        }
        if (r < RADIUS) {
            mSmallCircleColor = PRESSED_COLOR;
            mAngle = (float) (180 * Math.atan2(event.getY() - h2, event.getX() - w2) / Math.PI);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float w2 = getWidth() / 2f;
        float h2 = getHeight() / 2f;
        mMatrix.reset();
        mMatrix.postRotate(mAngle);
        mMatrix.postTranslate(w2, h2);

        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        mPaint.setColor(0x88ffffff);
        canvas.drawPath(mCircle, mPaint);
        mPaint.setColor(mSmallCircleColor);
        canvas.drawPath(mSmallCircle, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: click on the small circle and it becomes red, then move it around the big circle

Comment: i tried that and nothing happends..it doesn't become red and doesn't move. please advice

Comment: i just see two whitish circles, one small which is at the right edge of the bigger circle and thats it. so interaction on touch. cld u pls try the code at ur end

Comment: yes it works with the apk. alright i shall debug and see what is the problem. I have one request. U have used matrix and path to basically move the small circle around the bigger one. I am always confused with matrix. could you pls explain how matrix is used for moving objects in android

Comment: its basically like Canvas.translate, Canvas.rotate and Canvas.scale but all in one - matrix combines all of these three methods

Comment: so in this case, bsaically the big circle also rotates as the canvas rotates. But we see the shift of only the small circle with respect to the big circle. Am i correct in that assumption?

Comment: yes, but you can draw big circle before calling canvas.concat() and it will not rotate, it all depends on what you want to do

Comment: Also, hopefully one last question. The angle that u calculate for rotation of the canvas. is that the angle from 0(3'0 clock) Anticlock wise? or is it some other angle?

Comment: oh so u mean that if u draw the big circle and then rotate the canvas via convas.cancat().. then the big circle already drawn would not also get rotated? coz if that is the case then it would be very useful for me

Comment: no if you draw somwthing (rect for example) and then call canvas.concat() to rotate/scale/translate the canvas only new things are transformed but the rect stays in its place, try to play with canvas translate() and you will see how it works

Comment: I used ur code in my app. but i am not being able to rotate at the proper angle. i shall post the code. could you please have a look as to what angle calculation is going wrong?

Comment: it rotates half clockwise and other half CCW

Comment: the code doesnt compile and its imho too complex to analize, its is probably modified version of a class extending ViewGroup as i see ImageView unused fields, one advice: take my working code add add new features step by step or you will never get what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rectangle of your touch point and the rectangle(position) of your inner circle and check if they cross over with the Intersects method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle)

Your canvas onTouchListener can do whatever it needs to do if the touchpoint intersect your circle.

e.g:

```
    // Create a rectangle from the point of touch
    Rect touchpoint = new Rect(x,y,10,10);

    // Create a rectangle from the postion of the circle.
    Rect myCircle=new Rect(10,10,20,20);

    if (Rect.intersects(myCircle,touchpoint)){
        Log.d("The circle was touched");
    }
```

Comment: could you pls give a small exmaple